# ActiveModel::Serializer Caching - undefined method `fetch_or_store' for ThreadSafe::Cache

Tags: ruby, caching, thread-safety, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I just upgraded my AMS gem to `0.10.0.rc1` in hopes of getting some better caching functionality. I am trying to cache some AppLabels and the serializer there looks like this:

```
class AppLabelSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  cache key: 'app_label', expires_in: 3.hours
  attributes :id, :key, :label, :label_plural

  def key
    object.app_label_dictionary.key
  end

end
```

And then I hit one of the AppLabel end points with PostMan and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `fetch_or_store' for #<ThreadSafe::Cache:0x007fcf70821378>):
  app/controllers/v1/app_labels_controller.rb:22:in `auth_index'
```

I checked `app_labels_controller.rb` on line 22 and it is this method:

```
def auth_index
  render json: AppLabel.non_event
end
```

Which is calling an AppLabel scope:

```
scope :non_event, -> {joins(:app_label_dictionary).where(app_label_dictionary: {event_label: false} )}
```

I'm not familiar enough with AMS caching or Rails' Threadsafe elements to know what's going on here.

Any thoughts?